# Detect available open WiFi networks using Python

Tags: python, wifi

Is there some way I can detect available WiFi networks, which are open, using Python? I know I can do it on my Ubuntu box, but I haven't received my Pi yet, so I haven't been able to run the same code on it.

Thanks!

PS - Here's the code I use on Ubuntu.

```
from gi.repository import NetworkManager, NMClient

nmc = NMClient.Client.new()
devs = nmc.get_devices()

for dev in devs:
    if dev.get_device_type() == NetworkManager.DeviceType.WIFI:
        for ap in dev.get_access_points():
            print ap.get_ssid()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no module 'gi' installed on raspi by default, but nobody can stop you from installing it manually. other than that, there's a nice command `iwlist` that shows a lot of information about available networks, so I suppose in the unlikely event you cannot install 'gi' on raspberry, you may just run `iwlist` from python and catch/parse the output.

Comment: Ah, nice! Well. Gotta wait for another week before I get my Pi. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the code below that works for me, on a Pi 4 using Python 3.7.

```
# os.popen(): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/os_popen.htm
networks= os.popen('sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep ESSID').read()
# Parse all found networks list in a clean list 'networkslist'
networkslist= re.findall(r'"(.+?)"', networks)
# Print all networks to a list on screen
self.window.networklistview.addItems(networkslist)
```

It uses iwlist and makes a list available on the variable networklist. Regex is used to extract useful info. The last line offerst networklist to a list viewer from Qt. Some insight came from here [Wi-Fi scanning and displaying using Python run by PHP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69084/wi-fi-scanning-and-displaying-using-python-run-by-php/72907#72907)